# Is it possible to group counts by hour in MS Access and ensure any hours without values are listed in results with 0?

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

Here is where I am at so far with a query. The *submitted* field is a date/time field that records the time and date a ticket was submitted. The *id* is a unique identifier for each ticket. I need to count the number of tickets submitted every hour for each day of the year. The table contains all tickets for a single year. For any hours where no tickets were submitted, I need to list a 0 value, which is where I am having a problem.

```
SELECT DateValue(submitted) AS [date], DatePart("h", submitted) AS [hour], nz(COUNT(id), 0) AS [total_tickets]
FROM table
GROUP BY DateValue(submitted), DatePart("h", submitted);
```

The results are not what I need:

| date | hour | total_tickets |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-Jan-21 | 0 | 1 |
| 01-Jan-21 | 1 | 5 |
| 01-Jan-21 | 2 | 1 |
| 01-Jan-21 | 5 | 1 |
| 01-Jan-21 | 6 | 12 |
| 01-Jan-21 | 8 | 1 |

No tickets were submitted in the hours of 3, 4, & 7, thus no values are included in the results. However, I need those missing hours to be displayed with corresponding 0s in the *total_tickets* field. I am having a hard time finding a way to do this in Access SQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is not trivial. Typically you use **number table(s)** which you LEFT JOIN with your actual data.

Here is an explanation of the concept (in SQL Server you can create such a table on the fly with SQL, in Access you would use VBA and store it permamently):
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

So in your case I would create:

**nbrDate**:

| nDate |
| --- |
| 01-Jan-21 |
| 02-Jan-21 |
| 03-Jan-21 |
| etc. |

**nbrHour**:

| nHour |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| ... |
| 23 |

With these you build a query that does a cartesian product of dates * hours, giving a row for each combination (i.e. a row for each hour of each day):

```
SELECT d.nDate, h.nHour
FROM nbrDate d, nbrHour h
```

And finally you LEFT JOIN the result with your original query, returning either the total_tickets from your query or 0 if there wasn't a matching row:

```
SELECT n.nDate, n.nHour, Nz(q.total_tickets, 0) AS total_tickets
FROM nbrQuery n LEFT JOIN yourQuery q 
ON n.nDate = q.date AND n.nHour = q.hour
[WHERE n.nDate is in the range you want to report]
```

Note that this is all air code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiplying query (*Cartesian* join) to generate the hours, then join these with those submitted:

```sql
SELECT 
    query1.datehour, 
    Count(table.id) AS total_hours
FROM 

(SELECT DISTINCT 
    10 * Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10) + Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10) AS Id, 
    DateAdd("h",[Id], DateValue(submitted)) AS datehour
FROM 
    [table], 
    MSysObjects AS Uno, 
    MSysObjects AS Deca
WHERE 
    (10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10) + Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10)) < 24) AS query1 

LEFT JOIN 
    [table] 
    ON query1.datehour = table.submitted
GROUP BY 
    query1.datehour;
```

Output:

```
datehour            total_hours
------------------- -----------
01-01-2021           1
01-01-2021 01:00:00  5
01-01-2021 02:00:00  1
01-01-2021 03:00:00  0
01-01-2021 04:00:00  0
01-01-2021 05:00:00  1
01-01-2021 06:00:00 12
01-01-2021 07:00:00  0
01-01-2021 08:00:00  1
01-01-2021 09:00:00  0
01-01-2021 10:00:00  0
01-01-2021 11:00:00  0
01-01-2021 12:00:00  0
01-01-2021 13:00:00  0
01-01-2021 14:00:00  0
01-01-2021 15:00:00  0
01-01-2021 16:00:00  0
01-01-2021 17:00:00  0
01-01-2021 18:00:00  0
01-01-2021 19:00:00  0
01-01-2021 20:00:00  0
01-01-2021 21:00:00  0
01-01-2021 22:00:00  0
01-01-2021 23:00:00  0
```