# Populate Time Range In MS-Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am making a scheduling tool, which runs off of five-minute increments tied to the IDs of timeslots on another table. These timeslots have a start time, and stop time which are separate fields in the same record, and can be entered using a form, and I would like to create a range of five-minute increments as records between these two times.

The ultimate goal is to use these timeslots to make an outlook-style gui to show when there are timeslots.

I have been struggling to find a quick way to fill them in Access, and my attempts at coding are so pathetic I'm too embarrassed to show them.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated,
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Create a range where - records in a table or as a combobox list?

Comment: Some examples of calendars [here](https://www.msaccessgurus.com/tool/CalendarMaker.htm). Also, an example of creating a _datetime range_ in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73660562/3527297).

Comment: @June7 the start and stop time values are stored as separate fields in the same record which is assigned an ID. The increments are stored in another table as individual records for each five-minute increment.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to create a batch of five-minute increment records associated with a particular date. More than one way to accomplish. Simplest may be to have a table of time records. Each record would have a time value: 10:00, 10:05, etc. Then on UNBOUND form user selects time range start and end from comboboxes and enters a date in a textbox. An SQL action statement in VBA could be:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblSchedules(SchedDate, SchedTime) " & _
             "SELECT #" & Me.tbxDate & "#, Mins FROM tblTimes " & _
             "WHERE Mins BETWEEN '" & Me.cbxStart & "' AND '" & Me.cbxEnd & "'"
```

Without this table of time records, VBA would use a looping structure to save one record at a time to destination table.

```
Dim strT As String, db As DAO.Database
strT = Me.cbxStart
Set db = CurrentDb
Do While strT <= Me.cbxEnd
    db.Execute "INSERT INTO tblSchedules(SchedDate, SchedTime) VALUES(#" & Me.tbxDate & "#, '" & strT & "')"
    strT = Format(DateAdd("n", 5, CDate(strT)), "hh:nn")
Loop
```

In these examples, time value is text, not an actual date/time type. This means a structure of "hh:nn" in 24-hour time: "01:00" ... "24:00". If you prefer to save as number or as a date/time type, modify tables and code as appropriate. Keep in mind that midnight for date/time type is stored without a time component and Format() function displays as `12:00:00 AM` or `00:00:00`. Example: `Format(#1/1/2022#, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss AM/PM")` displays as **01/01/2022 12:00:00 AM**. Ranges crossing midnight causes complication.